# Multiple parameters on Angular Filter Pipe

Tags: html, angular, pipe

Ok, so the problem I am having here now is that I am trying to put multiple filters on a pipe for a search result page, where the data is being extracted from an api. How exactly do I incorporate different parameters to this filter pipe?

Link to app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/flight-example?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Here is the Pipe logic:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(items: any, max_price: any, depature_city: any): any {
    if (max_price === undefined) return 0;   

    // Filter each
    return  items.filter(t=> {
      // For Maximum Price
      if (t.price.amount <= max_price) {
        return t;
      }

      // For Depature City, also where I am having trouble
if (depature_city && items.depature.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(depature_city.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
            return items;
        }
    })
  }

}
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<div>
  <label> Maximum Price </label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="max_price">

  <label> Depature City </label>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="depature_city">
<p>Result:</p>
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let group of displayItems  | filter: max_price:depature_city">
     City: {{group.departure.city}} <br>
     Price :   {{group.price.amount}}
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let flight of group.segments">
        Flight No:  {{flight.flightNumber}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is the last time I am going to post a question about this app I swear.

Comment: What is your actual question? What should anyone expect in the demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your logic to filter from both conditions and return,

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(items: any, max_price: any, depature_city: any): any {
    if (max_price === undefined) return 0;   
    var filtereditems : any = [];
    // Filter each
    if (max_price){   
      filtereditems = items.filter(t=>t.price.amount <= max_price);
     }
    if(depature_city){
       console.log("departure city",depature_city);
       filtereditems =  items.some(t=>  t.departure.city.includes(depature_city));
    }
  if(depature_city && max_price){
       console.log("departure city",depature_city);
       filtereditems =  items.find(t=>  t.departure.city.includes(depature_city));

    }
    console.log("filtered",filtereditems);
     return filtereditems;
  }

}
```

The above code needs to be checked, it just applies the logic

Comment: His question is not clear enough to understand exactly what he want, he even forget to ask a specific question.

Comment: @hdjemai  I got to understand from the demo he attached

Comment: thanks its works, just need to make some adjustments.